GKE Nodes restart random
I created cluster and node pools by terraform modules. I configured module google_container_node_pool with basic configurations is:
resource "google_container_node_pool" "cache" {
    name       = "cache"
    location   = "asia-southeast1"
    cluster    = my-cluster

    node_count = 6

    node_config {
        preemptible  = true
        machine_type = "e2-medium"
        image_type = "cos_containerd"
        disk_type = "pd-standard"
        disk_size_gb = 20
        labels = {
            role = "cache"
        }
    }
}

When I created successfully. Sometimes, node is restarted randomly. Can I check why it's restarted?
I expect that the GKE nodes are not restart anymore

You are using preemptible nodes which can be interrupted at any time (at least once in 24 hours but more often depending on the type, size, region).
While they will also be interrupted, I'd recommend using Spot VMs instead as they are not mandatorily restarted every 24 hours (but they of course can be preempted at any time also).

I change Provisioning Model to Standard. Let's I monitor that nodes have restarted yet.
Thank you about your answer.
